# How to get user by firstname using a $http service in angular js with Mongodb database

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am trying to fetch a single user from my mongoDB database.

I have a service that works like this:

**The service:**

```
app.service('UsersService', function($http, $routeParams) {
  var getAllUrl = '/users';

  this.getSingleUser = function() {
    return $http.get(getAllUrl/$routeParams.firstname)
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.data;
            })
  }
});
```

And then I have the controller.

**The controller:**

```
app.controller('singleContactCtrl',
  function($scope, UsersService, $routeParams) {

   // Get single contact

   UsersService.getSingleUser().then(function(data) {
     $scope.singlecontact = data;
   });
});
```

On my api when I do /users/firstname I get my json data. Is there something I am doing wrong? Using the resource is quite straight forward but I would like to get some more insight on how the $http works.

Comment: Could You do $scope.singlecontact = JSON.parse(data);?

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this as well but no effect again. Returned a 404.

Comment: There are at least 3 things wrong here. 1) $http.get expects a string argument, your argument is variable divided by another variable. 2) The 'getSingleUser' method should take an argument (firstname), and you should call that method from your controller with the arg. try those 2 things first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the url `getAllUrl/$routeParams.firstname` should be changed to `getAllUrl + '/' + $routeParams.firstname`

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactly the issue